# Could someone please help this last question? minimal polynomials and kernels

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

[Invariant Subspace and Direct Sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2309881/invariant-subspace-and-direct-sum/2310556#comment6813763_2310556)

As I was reading through this question from another thread, I was wondering how to approach the very last bit, where it said "show that $S^m(W)=0$ for some $m$".

I can directly show it from the fact that $0$ is the only eigenvalue. However, how can I show from part (i) that the statement is true?

I can see that $W = Ker(S^r) ⊕ Im(S^r)$ for some $r$ by (i) but how do I continue? Also I can see that if $W=ker(S^r)$ then $S^r(W)=0$. Also how can I link the part where it asks about eigenvalues to proving the statement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $n\geq 0,$ $S^n(W)$ is an $S$-invariant subspace of $W.$  Therefore, if $S^r(W)\neq 0,$ the restriction $S|_{S^r(W)}$ only has eigenvalue $0,$ and hence $$\ker(S^r) \cap \text{im}(S^r) \supseteq \ker(S) \cap S^r(W) = \ker(S|_{S^r(W)}) \neq 0$$

Comment: Thanks but I don't get why would that imply $S^m=0$ for some m and how will that m be related to r?

Comment: You've written $W = \ker(S^r) \oplus \text{im}(S^r)$ in your question as a starting point, which in particular means $\ker(S^r) \cap \text{im}(S^r) = 0$.

What I've shown is that $$S^r(W) \neq 0 \implies \ker(S^r) \cap \text{im}(S^r) \neq 0$$ so by the contrapositive, $$\ker(S^r) \cap \text{im}(S^r) = 0 \implies S^r(W) = 0.$$

In other words, _for the same $r$ you chose_, we have $S^r(W)=0$ (and hence $m=r$ works)

Comment: As stated, the (first) inclusion, which is based on $\ker(S^r)\supseteq\ker(S)$, is not valid in case $r=0$; I cannot see where it is given or follows that $r>0$, so I guess that formally you would need to treat $r=0$ as a separate (though boring) case.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen If $r$ were arbitrary, this would be a valid criticism, but $r$ is far from arbitrary: it is chosen in the question so that $\ker(S^r) = \ker(S^n)$ for all $n \geq r.$  If anything, you might argue I need to include this justification in my post, but $r=0$ is not a separate case.

Comment: The situation of the linked question is a bit complicated, but if in that post you take $T=N+\lambda I$ with $N$ nilpotent and $\lambda\neq0$, then one finds ($T$ is invertible, so) $r=0$, and $S=N$, with $W$ equal to the whole space; all the hypotheses of its point (ii) are satisfied. Also your extra hypothesis $S^r(W)\neq0$ is satisfied (provided $\dim V>0$), and $S$ indeed only has eigenvalue $0$. But $\ker(S^r)\cap\text{im}(S^r)=0 \not\supseteq\ker(S)=\ker(S) \cap S^r(W)$ contrary to what you claim, showing that this case needs to be taken separately. Which is all I claimed.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Again, that's not how the exponent is defined.  The exponent for $S$ is nowhere defined to be the same as the exponent for $T.$  Further, when $S$ is known to be nilpotent, the sequence of kernels is eventually the whole space, so in that case, the algorithm in (i) yields the minimal $r$ such that $S^r = 0.$  In this context, the last part of (ii) is simply showing that $$\text{Every linear operator on a finite dimensional subspace with no nonzero eigenvalue is nilpotent.}$$